Flutter web deployment on Caprover
I made a web site using flutter web, the web site work exactly how I want.
I usually deploy my work with caprover for simplicity but it is the first time I want to deploy a flutter web application.
I created a Dockerfile:
...

# Build the Flutter web application
RUN flutter build web --release

# Use Nginx to serve the app
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=0 /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html

# config nginx lestener
RUN sed -i 's/listen       80;/listen       8080;/' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=0 /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 8080 and start Nginx server
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

This dockerfile works well on my computer.
But, when I want to run it on caprover, I get this error:
...
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.5
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 13.2.1 20231014 (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014)
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.4.0-162-generic
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: signal 3 (SIGQUIT) received, shutting down
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 28#28: gracefully shutting down
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 28#28: exiting
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 28#28: exit
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: signal 3 (SIGQUIT) received, shutting down
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 29#29: gracefully shutting down
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 29#29: exiting
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 29#29: exit
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 28
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: worker process 28 exited with code 0
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: exit
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 29
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: worker process 29 exited with code 0
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: exit


The full logs at the end of the post

I think that caprover shutdown the instance of nginx created by my dockerfile but I'm not really sure and I don't know nginx very well. The other apps that I deployed on my caprover work very well but they don't use nginx
How can I fix the problem or what should I use to serve ma web site? (I tried with python3 -m http.server 8080 but the routing doesn't work)
Moreover, with this dockerfile if I go on localhost:8080/ I get my page working properly, but if I go on localhost:8080/another_page I get an 404 page not found page while this page exists in dev mode and I don't understand what append
The full caprover error log:
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/04/30 20:38:47 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2024/04/30 20:38:47 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.5
2024/04/30 20:38:47 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 13.2.1 20231014 (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014)
2024/04/30 20:38:47 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.4.0-162-generic
2024/04/30 20:38:47 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/04/30 20:38:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2024/04/30 20:38:47 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/04/30 20:49:10 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2024/04/30 20:49:10 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.5
2024/04/30 20:49:10 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 13.2.1 20231014 (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014)
2024/04/30 20:49:10 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.4.0-162-generic
2024/04/30 20:49:10 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/04/30 20:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2024/04/30 20:49:10 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.5
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 13.2.1 20231014 (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014)
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.4.0-162-generic
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2024/04/30 20:49:13 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: signal 3 (SIGQUIT) received, shutting down
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 28#28: gracefully shutting down
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 28#28: exiting
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 28#28: exit
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: signal 3 (SIGQUIT) received, shutting down
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 29#29: gracefully shutting down
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 29#29: exiting
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 29#29: exit
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 28
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: worker process 28 exited with code 0
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: exit
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 29
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: worker process 29 exited with code 0
2024/04/30 20:49:16 [notice] 1#1: exit


I faced the same problem but my solution was to use pocketbase to serve the flutter files
and it works perfect for me

in the one click applications section install pocketbase
access the application volume and create the pb_public folder
paste the generated flutter build files


flutter build web --web-renderer html --release
4) all ready! Your web application with Flutter will be online

I hope it is useful.

It is an interesting way of doing it. I fix my probleme by serving my app with a python server
